# Include font-awesome in bootstrap sass via Bower

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I've installed `bootstrap-sass-official` and `font-awesome` using bower. I've tried all the possible combinations to include the fontawesome in bootstrap using scss.

The most probable solution is specifying in my app's `main.scss` file the following:

```
$fa-font-path: "../bower_components/font-awesome/fonts";
@import "font-awesome/scss/font-awesome";
@import '../../bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap.scss';
```

And to comment out the `@import "bootstrap/glyphicons";` inside the main `bootstrap.scss` file.

If I launch my `grunt serve` at `http://localhost:9000/` (I'm using a gruntfile from the default yeoman webapp) I can see my app running.

I can see my `main.css` file with all the *fontawesome* classes and inside it the reference url to the location of the fonts (`../bower_components/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot`).

Everything seems ok but whenever I use a FontAwesome icon, for example `<span class="fa-star"></span>` I get an empty square box instead of the icon. I'm missing something I can't see...

Comment: FA don't work with <span class="fa-star"></span> you have to prefix with fa : <span class="fa fa-star"></span>

Comment: seriously? I took me 24 hours to realize my stupidity ;) @TheLittlePig if you write your comment as an answer I will accept it

Comment: Or we can delete the question because maybe has nothing to do with bower at all

Comment: Your tags have been cleared. Hope it's working now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<span class="fa-star"></span>
```

It won't do anything.

In order to use Font awesome, you need to prefix the class by 'fa' :

```
<span class="fa fa-star"></span>
```